# A main php-page with several subpages

Tags: php

Is it possible to have a mainpage with the whole main HTML-framework, and then every other subpages included to be only activated when clicked on in navigation bar. Like if you click subpage1, the content is replaced by subpage1.php, and vica versa when clicked on subpage2. I understand you have to use a variable of some sort, but I can't find a good tutorial on this to fully understand the setup and what php code I have to include in each of these pages - if any. Let me show you a draft of what I mean:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <?php 
        include ('main.php'); 
        include ('subpage1.php'); <!--Active-->
        include ('subpage2.php'); <!--When clicked on, replaces subpage1-->
      ?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use a `switch`, and it is normally done with ajax.
Anyhow, let's say you decide which page is selected with a `GET`.
In our main page you'll have this

```
 <?php 
if (isset($_GET["page"]) && is_numeric($_GET["page"])){
$page = $_GET["page"];
switch ($page){
case "1": include ('main.php');
break; 
case "2": include ('subpage1.php');
break;
 default;
       include("default.php");
break;

 }
}
      ?>
```

Something like that.